# Program portability issues (Windows XP to Windows 7)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I had originally written a program for Windows XP, now I want to run it on Windows 7. I'm getting an error as follows.

> runtime error 713 - application defined or object defined error

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't copied some of the references from the XP environment to Win7. Check from your IDE what libraries do you reference and copy those dlls too along the exe.

Comment: Did you even need that DLL in the first place?   Or is this a VB6 program?